# Returning arbitrary fields using the Solr Suggester component

Tags: solr, autosuggest, search-suggestion

I'm looking to use the Solr [Suggester](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester) component for serving up search auto-complete suggestions.

I have created a field in my schema:

```
<fieldType name="text_autocomplete" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

While my solrconfig.xml looks like:

```
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">suggest</str>
        <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
        <str name="field">title_autocomplete</str>
        <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>
<requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
        <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

I am getting sensible results coming back, which is great.  However, I would like to return the id field for the matching document rather than the field I am attempting to match against.

Comment: I wonder, what is the use case of having doc ids right when the autosuggested results are displayed?

Comment: D_K I want to show the count along with search suggestions. Any idea how to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion component is made to return you the most correlating words for a partial match to what you have typed in. Then if you need the documents that have a specific word from the list of suggestions, shoot another query to Solr (this time a different search handler) and get the doc ids back.